# opencv IplImage To UIImage with ARC leak

Tags: iphone, opencv, uiimage, memory-leaks

I'm converting a stream of IplImages to UIImage using this function:

```
 +(UIImage *)createUIImageFromIplImage:(IplImage *)image
{       
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:image->imageData length:image->imageSize];

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(image->width, image->height,
                                       image->depth, image->depth * image->nChannels, image->widthStep,
                                       colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
                                       provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    UIImage* ret = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return ret;
}
```

However, I get a memory warning after a few images and then a crash . Running in instruments revelas that the problematic line is where memory is allocated is:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:image->imageData length:image->imageSize];
```

Somehow this memory is never released.
How can this be fixed?

Comment: Is this method being called on the main thread, or detached?

Comment: I had same problem. I am calling this function on main thread.

Comment: hi i had same problem. do u have any solution ? Thanks in advance .